# How to make Deployment, Ingress and Service Yaml file on one file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I want to make a `YAML` file with Deployment, Ingress, and Service (maybe with clusterissuer, issuer and cert) on one file, how can I do that? I tried

```
kubectl apply -f (name_file.yaml)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it with three dashes on your yaml file
like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mock
spec:
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mock
spec:
```

Source : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/kubernetes-merge-multiple-yaml-into-one-e8844479a73a